# How to fix ActionCable not appending data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm setting up ActionCable for my Chatroom channel in rails.

The problem is that everytime a logged in user sends a message, say UserA, the message won't get appended to the chatroom. I have tried logging in another user at the same time, say UserB, the message from UserB got appended to the chatroom of UserA, but not userB and vice versa.

/app/channels/chatroom_channel.rb

```
class ChatroomChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "chatroom_channel"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end

end
```

/app/assets/javascripts/channels/chatroom.coffee

```
App.chatroom = App.cable.subscriptions.create "ChatroomChannel",

connected: ->
# Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server

disconnected: ->
# Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

received: (data) ->
  alert data
  $('#messages').append(data)
  $('#message_content').val = ''
  scrollToBottom()
  return

scrollToBottom = ->
  if $('#messages').length > 0
    last_message = $('#messages')[0]
    last_message.scrollTop = last_message.scrollHeight - (last_message.clientHeight)

$(document).ready ->
  scrollToBottom()
  return    

jQuery(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  scrollToBottom()
  return   
  # Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
```

This is part of my chatroom view: /app/views/chatrooms/index.html.erb

```
<div class="twelve wide column">
  <div class="ui fluid raised card chatbox">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="ui feed" id="messages">
        <%= render @messages %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="extra content">
      <%= form_for(@message, html: {class: "ui reply form", role: "form"}, url: message_path) do |f| %>
        <div class="field">
          <div class="ui fluid icon input">
            <%= f.text_field :body, id: "message_content"%>
            <%= f.button '<i class="bordered inverted orange edit icon"></i>'.html_safe %>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have changed the development from `async` to `redis` in `config/cable.yml` but still did not do the trick. Thank you for reading in advance

Comment: Hi! could you describe the problem in detail? like what fail? what success? what your expectation?

Comment: Ah sorry if I didn't put it nicely. The message I send to channels doesn't get appended, but if other users do it, their message will append. I have to refresh my web browser to do so. When I checked, the message I pass to my channel doesn't hit "received" function